# openssl/keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Input not an X.509 certificate

Tags: java, ssl, https, keytool

I have created certificate through Openssl

```
Openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout tls.key -out tls.crt -subj "/CN=nginxsvc/O=nginxsvc"
```

and then created a PKCS#12 file using OpenSSL:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in tls.crt -inkey tls.key -out tls.p12
```

and after that convert it to JKS using

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore tls.p12  -srcstoretype PKCS12  -destkeystore tls.jks  -deststoretype JKS
```

now when importing this jks file through keytool like this

```
keytool -import -noprompt -trustcacerts -alias "nginxsvc" -file tls.jks -keystore "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_152\jre\lib\security\cacerts"
```

I am getting

> keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Input not an X.509 certificate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-import` needs a certificate file, not a JKS.
Try :

```
keytool -import -noprompt -trustcacerts -alias "nginxsvc" -file tls.crt -keystore "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_152\jre\lib\security\cacerts"
```

Comment: What if i will import openssl generate certificate like this `keytool -import -file C:\Code_Base\Certificates\NGINX_150\tls.crt -storepass changeit -keystore "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_152\jre\lib\security\cacerts"` then i dont need to convert certificate. Is this approach also fine

Comment: I did what you mentioned bt i am getting 16:30:21,046 ERROR [org.keycloak.adapters.OAuthRequestAuthenticator] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) failed to turn code into token: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: hostname in certificate didn't match: <135.250.138.150> != <nginxsvc>

Comment: Yes, you can import the certificate directly.

Comment: The certificate should be generated for a FQDN (example : xxx.yyy.com) and you should request this FQDN (https://xxx.yyy.com). You can use a shortname such as nginxsvc if you want, but then you have to request it and not its IP address.